# Realization of iterative root-finding algorithm

Tags: delphi, math

I need realize algorithm for finding roots with specified precision by iterative method. Main idea of this method is Cn=f(Cn-1); C0=(A+B)/2; where a,b-boundary of interval comprising roots. I wrote this code(in Delphi7)

```
program iter;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,Math;

function GetCn(Cn1:Double):Double;
begin
   Result:=Cn1+sin(1/Cn1);
end;

var
  a,b:Double;
  Cn,Cn1:Double;
  eps,eps1:Double;

begin
  a:=1.2;b:=2; 
  Cn:=(a+b)/2;
  Write('Input precision ');Readln(eps);
  eps1:=Abs(Cn-Cn1);
  While eps1>eps do
  begin
    Cn1:=Cn;
    Cn:=GetCn(Cn);
    eps1:=Abs(Cn-Cn1);
  end;
  Writeln(Cn);
  Readln;
end.
```

In test data f(x)=x-2+sin(1/x); a:=1.2 b:=2.0 eps:=0.001 my programm give answer  1.00000143538244E+0003, but in set of problems is answer 1,3077

Why is it so? Where do i error? How to correct?

P.S Sorry fo my English

Comment: That algorithm doesn't look like a root finder to me. What do you think the name of that algo is?

Comment: [Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8) about it

Comment: Your code is so bad that it is hard to correct. `Cn1` is not initialized, `Cn` can mean both argument value and function value...

Comment: Well, I'd like to help, but you've got to give us something to work with. Try your algo with f=x^2, a=1, b=2 and you'll see that it is not a root finder, but it is in fact an elaborate algorithm for generating overflow errors.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand,what must I give you?

Comment: Cn=f(Cn-1) may work for finding the fixed points of f, not its roots. Which are you trying to to find?

Comment: Some indication of why you think your algorithm is a root finder. As I show in my previous comment, it is not.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it not root finding algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is not a root finder. To recap, your recursive step is

C<sub>n</sub> = f(C<sub>n-1</sub>)

and you terminate when C<sub>n</sub> equals C<sub>n-1</sub> up to tolerance.

That algorithm may find fixed points, but it won't find roots. To find roots you need something like Newton's method, bisection, secant method, etc.

Even as a fixed point finder, your code is broken. The first time the code performs the termination test, it reads the value of `Cn1` before initializing it.

---

In the comments you tell us that you asked the wrong question, and that you are trying to find fixed points. In which case you just need to modify the code to avoid reading variables before they are initialised:

```
begin
  a:=1.2;b:=2; 
  Cn:=(a+b)/2;
  Write('Input precision ');Readln(eps);
  repeat
    Cn1:=Cn;
    Cn:=GetCn(Cn);
    eps1:=Abs(Cn-Cn1);
  until eps1<=eps;
  Writeln(Cn);
  Readln;
end.
```

Also the function in your code doesn't match the one in the question. I don't know which one is right.

Comment: OK, I asked lecturer, he answered that I must find fixed points, not roots. How can I improve my code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it sounds like you just did his homework assignment for him.